# Laravel authentication & authorisation with REMOTE_USER

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I've got the following setup:

Apache Server 2.4.x which uses Kerberos for SSO
Laravel 5.5
PHP 7.x
MSSQL Database 12 with existing database structure, Usertable can be customized

In my Laravel application a user can access the application only if he/she already passed the apache login which means i can retrieve the REMOTE_USER variable from the server with

```
$user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
```

What i intend to do is to use the Laravel authentication and authorisation for the rest of the application. I've looked into a lot of examples but found nothing which really suits.

Can anybody give a hint how to authenticate the $user in Laravel when accessing the application to get the credentials?

Comment: I guess this could be possible with  Auth::attempt(['email' =>  $user, 'password' => $password])) - will post the solution here!

Answer (score 0):

After hours i managed to get it work:

I user the Homecontroller and the

```
public function index()
```

Inside the function index() i used the following code:

```
$user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']; // user from apache $env variable 
                                 // authenticated via kerberos

$user = DB::table('users')
    ->where('users.name',"=",$user)
    ->first();
    
Auth::attempt(['name' => $user->name, 'password' => "xxx"]);
    
return view('start');
```

Maybe it's useful for somebody!

Answer (score 0):

The Homecontroller was not sufficient so i created a middleware using it in every controller like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('logincustom');

}
```

The middleware for this

```
class CustomLogin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']; // get remoteusername
        if (Auth::user() != null) { // if user not null
            if ($user ==  Auth::user()->login) { // check if remoteuser is equal to currently login user

                    if (Auth::check()) {
                        return $next($request);
                    }
            }
        }

        $user = DB::table('settings.user')
            ->where('login',"=",$user)
            ->first();

         $authenticated = Auth::attempt(['login' => $user->login, 'password' => "xxx"]);
        if ($authenticated == null ) {

            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }


       return $next($request);
    }
}
```

So this solved my problem for automatic logins based on and external, already authenticated user!